# Can an attribute be used to create/reformat content without Javascript, but only CSS?

Tags: css, html

[JS-Fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/sf7La9nv/)

```
<time datetime="2020-1-1"> </time>
```

with css:

```
time:empty:after{content:attr(datetime)}
```

shows:

```
2020-1-1
```

but can i reformat it somehow, to get something like:

```
01/01/19
```

without using Javascript, but only CSS? 
I'm sure this has been already asked an been answered somewhere, but I just can't find it.

Comment: ......nope.....

Comment: So hoping against hope, that someone smarter might have found a way?!  :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can parse the date in HTML then you can pick up each number and build the string however you'd like. I'm not sure if this would be a reasonable approach for you but I figured I'd post just in case.

```css
time {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

time:empty {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

time:empty::after {
  content: attr(data-month)"/"attr(data-day)"/"attr(data-year);
}
```

```html
<time datetime="2020-01-01" data-year="20" data-month="01" data-day="01"></time>
```

Comment: Clever use of content + attribs! +1

Comment: Very Clever! Not exactly what I wanted, but as long as there's no better suggestion I'll accept it! Thanks!